# Lumen Database [xxx] not configured

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to query one of my setup databases with Lumen. I created a configuration file like this:

**config/database.php**

```
return [
    'mysql' => [
        'domains' => [
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'domains'
        ],
        // Other connections here...
        'driver'  => 'mysql'
    ]
];
```

I then try to execute my query in my route like this

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
$app->get('/billing/saved/{id}', function($id){
    $data = DB::connection('domains')
            ->select('select billing_id, nickname
                from billing
                where user_id = 108649 and billing_id = ?', [$id]);
    return response()->json($data);
});
```

When it gets run, I get the following error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException in DatabaseManager.php line 238:
Database [domains] not configured.

in DatabaseManager.php line 238
at DatabaseManager->getConfig('domains') in DatabaseManager.php line 157
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('domains') in DatabaseManager.php line 67
at DatabaseManager->connection('domains') in Facade.php line 210
at Facade::__callStatic('connection', array('domains')) in routes.php line 68
at DB::connection('domains') in routes.php line 68
at Closure->{closure}('1')
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array('1')) in Container.php line 502
at Container->call(object(Closure), array('id' => '1')) in Application.php line 1263
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array('1', array(object(Closure)), array('id' => '1'))) in Application.php line 1237
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array('1', array(object(Closure)), array('id' => '1'))) in Application.php line 1211
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('1', array(object(Closure)), array('id' => '1'))) in Application.php line 1163
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}() in Application.php line 1390
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1164
at Application->dispatch(null) in Application.php line 1104
at Application->run() in index.php line 28
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Not really used lumen, but going by some quick reading, should the `mysql` string be `connections` and the `driver` line be inside `domains`?

Comment: After some testing, that looks like it fixes it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you already figured out the answer, though this might help other users having the same issue or looking for the correct settings.

```
return ['connections' => [
  'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'db_name',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'db_password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. I see this is from `config/database.php`. I have my info imported from the .env file, but beside that, it is the same. However if I set session driver to file, then it works, if to database, it doesn't. What the hell?