# Lumen database [] not configured after doing necessary steps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

I have read and tried to do the steps from these links, but my second database still will not configure. 
[Lumen - Create database connection at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215265/lumen-create-database-connection-at-runtime)
[Lumen Database [xxx] not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145002/lumen-database-xxx-not-configured)

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I've missed out?

This is my code:

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

DB_CONNECTION=mysql2
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

in my app.php I have added:
    $app->configure('database');

database.php

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database1'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8_unicode_ci'),
        'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
        'strict'    => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', false),
    ],

    'mysql2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database2'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8_unicode_ci'),
        'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
        'strict'    => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', false),
    ],
```

This is a sample connection to the database that I used:

```
$checkduplicate = DB::connection('database2')->table('authusers')->select('username')->where('username', $username)->get();
```

This is in my routes.php

```
$app->get('database2/register', 'Database2_DashboardController@registerAdmin');
```

$app->post('database2/register', 'Database2_DashboardController@registerAdmin');

Comment: Plz Explain Your Error

Comment: This is the error that I get: InvalidArgumentException 
Database [database2] not configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use connection variable **'mysql2'** instead of database name **'database2'**

```
 $checkduplicate = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('authusers')->select('username')->where('username', $username)->get();
```

Comment: I tried that too, but I still get the same error. My error is: database [database2] not configured.

Comment: Okay it works now! :) I just forgot to change one of the connections. Thank you so much!!